# Compare multiple array in kNN

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, knn

I am trying to get the accuracy of my kNN for different k values. The array A is the outcome of three different values of k. I want to compare for each raw in A with B and return an accuracy value for each. This is my code,

```
import numpy as np

A = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
B = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] 

predictions = np.array(A)
y_test = np.array(B)


def getAccuracy(y_test, predictions):
    correct = 0
    w = []
    for i in range(predictions.shape[0]): # I want to compare for each raw in A with B
        for x in range(len(y_test)):
            if y_test[x] == predictions[i,x]:
                correct += 1
                acc = (correct/len(y_test)) * 100.0
        return acc


    return w.append(acc)

test = getAccuracy(y_test, predictions)
print(test)
```

But I get the output as `0.0`. Thanks for helping me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a binary classification you don't have to compare the values, it can be done easily with a simple addition:

```
A = [[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1]]
B = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] 

predictions = np.array(A)
y_test = np.array(B)

for c in A:
    acc = sum([((x*y)+(x-1)*(y-1)) for x,y in zip(c,B)])/len(B)
    print(acc)
>>>0.7
>>>0.7
>>>0.8
```

so why `((x*y)+(x-1)*(y-1))` works. 
well if you try the four cases: `(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)` you'll see that for the ones where the classes are different, each part of the sum in equal to 0 and for the ones where classes are equal, only one part of the sum is not equal to 0 and is equal to 1. So for every step it put a 1 if classes are equal and a 0 otherwise.

It's a small trick that fasten a lot the way to compute accuracy.

Comment: could you please tell me what "((x*y)+(x-1)*(y-1))" does here? it is not clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Mass17 Updated

Comment: Okay got it!! Thanks a lot @Alexis